# Hide and Show divs below a button selection + class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

For example you have three buttons. Depending on the button you choose, a div will appear below it with another subset of buttons and continue like such. When you have clicked on a button it will turn yellow, and a class "selected" will show up on that button.  However lets say I have div 1, div 2, div 3, and div 4 all loaded. But I choose a different button on div 2. I want div 4 to disappear and essentially "reset", and div 3 button's selection to reset (as in the selection class gone).

Below: Lets say btn 1 and btn 4 is selected (yellow) and div 2 and div 3 are loaded now. But I choose btn 2 now, so selected(yellow) shows over btn 2, not btn 1. I NEED div 3 to disappear and div 2 to reset with NO "selected" class on anything. Essentially reset div 2 (the div below the button you selected and all div's below as well.)

I hope that makes a bit more sense. Let me know if I need to clarify further.

HTML EXAMPLE

```js
$(".div2, .div3, .div4, .div5").hide();

$('.btn1, .btn2, .btn3 ').click(function() {
  $('.div2').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn4, .btn5, .btn6 ').click(function() {
  $('.div3').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn7, .btn8, .btn9 ').click(function() {
  $('.div4').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn10, .btn11, .btn12 ').click(function() {
  $('.div5').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  color:grey;
}
.selected {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
    <button class="btn1 btn"><label for="btn1">Btn1</label></button>
    <button class="btn2 btn"><label for="btn2">Btn2</label></button>
    <button class="btn3 btn"><label for="btn3">Btn3</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
    <button class="btn4 btn"><label for="btn4">Btn4</label></button>
    <button class="btn5 btn"><label for="btn5">Btn5</label></button>
    <button class="btn6 btn"><label for="btn6">Btn6</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
    <button class="btn7 btn"><label for="btn7">Btn7</label></button>
    <button class="btn8 btn"><label for="btn8">Btn8</label></button>
    <button class="btn9 btn"><label for="btn9">Btn9</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div4">
    <button class="btn10 btn"><label for="btn10">Btn10</label></button>
    <button class="btn11 btn"><label for="btn11">Btn11</label></button>
    <button class="btn12 btn"><label for="btn12">Btn12</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.click`, you might want to use `.focus`.

Comment: @Goldenowner I don't think that's gonna help because (if I understand correctly) he wants to **select** the button.

Comment: Is your jQuery inside `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });` ?

Comment: so you're saying "Below: Lets say btn 1 and btn 4 is selected (yellow) and div 2 and div 3 are loaded now.".  Shouldn't divs 1 and 2 be loaded rather than 2 and 3?...

Comment: @JonathonHibbard you are correct. Currently in the two answers they hide only the first row. I need to hide any rows below the row that contains the  button you selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to go up to the `.row`, then use `nextAll` to get the other `.row`'s. then find the `div`'s to hide and then find the `button`'s with in them to remove the class.

then do something similar to show the `next` div.

```js
$(".div2, .div3, .div4, .div5").hide();

$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass(); 
  $(this).closest('.row').nextAll('.row').find('div').hide().find('button').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).closest('.row').next('.row').find('div').show();
});
```

```css
.btn {
  color:grey;
}
.selected {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
    <button class="btn1 btn"><label for="btn1">Btn1</label></button>
    <button class="btn2 btn"><label for="btn2">Btn2</label></button>
    <button class="btn3 btn"><label for="btn3">Btn3</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
    <button class="btn4 btn"><label for="btn4">Btn4</label></button>
    <button class="btn5 btn"><label for="btn5">Btn5</label></button>
    <button class="btn6 btn"><label for="btn6">Btn6</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
    <button class="btn7 btn"><label for="btn7">Btn7</label></button>
    <button class="btn8 btn"><label for="btn8">Btn8</label></button>
    <button class="btn9 btn"><label for="btn9">Btn9</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div4">
    <button class="btn10 btn"><label for="btn10">Btn10</label></button>
    <button class="btn11 btn"><label for="btn11">Btn11</label></button>
    <button class="btn12 btn"><label for="btn12">Btn12</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: of all my years dabbling with jquery. I never knew of "closest". I feel like a huge idiot. haha. Thank you BG101

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to answer in generic way but this code will do exactly what you are looking for. A generic way required more time.

```js
$(".div2, .div3, .div4, .div5").hide();

$('.btn1, .btn2, .btn3 ').click(function() {
  $('.div2').fadeIn("slow").find('.btn').removeClass('selected');
  $('.div3, .div4').fadeOut('slow');
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn4, .btn5, .btn6 ').click(function() {
  $('.div3').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn7, .btn8, .btn9 ').click(function() {
  $('.div4').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('.btn10, .btn11, .btn12 ').click(function() {
  $('.div5').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  color:grey;
}
.selected {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
    <button class="btn1 btn"><label for="btn1">Btn1</label></button>
    <button class="btn2 btn"><label for="btn2">Btn2</label></button>
    <button class="btn3 btn"><label for="btn3">Btn3</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
    <button class="btn4 btn"><label for="btn4">Btn4</label></button>
    <button class="btn5 btn"><label for="btn5">Btn5</label></button>
    <button class="btn6 btn"><label for="btn6">Btn6</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
    <button class="btn7 btn"><label for="btn7">Btn7</label></button>
    <button class="btn8 btn"><label for="btn8">Btn8</label></button>
    <button class="btn9 btn"><label for="btn9">Btn9</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div4">
    <button class="btn10 btn"><label for="btn10">Btn10</label></button>
    <button class="btn11 btn"><label for="btn11">Btn11</label></button>
    <button class="btn12 btn"><label for="btn12">Btn12</label></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 div5"></div>
</div>
```